# UTF-8 Extended ASCII character taking up 3 bytes unexpectedly

Tags: encoding, utf-8

In UTF-8, my understanding (and this can be confirmed by Wikipedia) is that any character within ASCII takes a single byte and any character up to `U+07FF` takes two. So, I assumed that the character `›` (`&rsaquo;`) should be encoded in two bytes, since it is inside the correct range (code point is `U+009B`).

However, when I type the following into my browser's console (Firefox), it gives me 3 instead of 2:

```
unescape(encodeURI("›")).length
```

(from https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/1010324)

Websites which display the length of UTF-8 encoded characters seem to agree - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `&rsaquo;` character is `U+203A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203a/index.htm), not `U+009B` (which is a non-printable escape code, ["control sequence introducer"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9b/index.htm)).

Comment: So UTF-8 encoding uses a _different_ version of extended ASCII than 'extended ASCII'?

Comment: Did you look at the links? The character `›` isn't part of extended ASCII at all. There is one that looks like it, but it's not a printable character.

Comment: There is no single well-defined character set whose name is "extended ASCII". The resource where you found this probably used this imprecise term to refer to [Windows code page 1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251).